# How to set background to list item in context action bar delete

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am making one android application in that I have listview.I wanted to delete listitem using context actionbar if I use listview.setonitemlong click listener it is showing delete menu on actionbar it is deleting also but my problem is when I select particular list item its background color is not changing please help me

code:

```
if (mActionMode != null) {
    return false;
}

mActionMode = this.startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
view.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set background color via this code

```
v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
```

Comment: how to remove background color if i don't want to delete